# Can I store logs into MySQL instead of log file using the loguru python library

Tags: mysql, logging, fastapi, loguru

I started using loguru to log errors and info in my FastAPI app. I want to store these logs in an existing MySQL database.

I have created a middleware and managed to log the errors/info and store them in `info.log` file. However, I want to store these logs in existing MySQL data instead of a file. I could not find any resource/tutorial explaining how. I believe that I should replace `logger.add("info.log",.....` in the code below with something else, but I have no clue what

```
from loguru import logger

app = FastAPI()

logger.add("info.log",format="Log: [{extra[log_id]}]: {time} | {level} | {message} ", level="INFO",  enqueue = True)

@app.middleware("http")
async def log_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
  
  log_id = generate_request_id()
  with logger.contextualize(log_id=log_id):
     ## some code
     logger.info(some logs")
     return response
```

Comment: I think that scheduled importing of an existing log file into MySQL database (see [LOAD DATA statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)) will be more simple solution.